# Clear Listbox when datasource is set Visual Basic Net

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have a listbox which has a datasource set and gets its content from an array. I tried to just do this code

```
Listbox1.Items.Clear()
```

Didn't work since the datasource is selected. I also tried stuff like

```
Listbox1.datasource = ""
```

Or something like `Listbox1.datasource = vbNULL`

etc. to make the datasource clean so I can remove all items from my listbox1

How can I achieve it, I was browsing through all of Stack Overflows responses, none of them have worked for me

Comment: when do you populate your listbox and when do you clear it? I was thinking that this code Listbox1.Items.Clear() works but you have somewhere in your code that calls a function to populate it again... hmm. just some thought.

Comment: Its a simple software. You click on the button for the first time and it starts a timer. The timer creates an array with strings in it and then passes the array entries to the listbox via datasource.
When I click the second time on the button, I want the listbox to be cleared and then start over again with populating the listbox via the timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is a WinForm application. 
Clear the datasource like this:

```
ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to be the exact solution that I was looking for. I just tried it with my WinForm app and it worked perfectly. Going to play around with my Win app now to see whether it completely works, but it seems like it!